Given a torsion free abelian group $G$ and $m> 1$, is it always true that $mG \cong G$?
Given a torsion-free abelian group $G$ and $m> 1$, define $mG =\left\{mg \mid g \in G\right\}$, is it always true that $mG \cong G$?
This is true for finitely generated abelian group and subgroups of $\mathbb Q^n$, does it hold in general?

I just realised that the map $g \mapsto mg$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $mG$.

Yes. It’s always surjective, and torsion-freeness implies it’s injective.
